# PHP code won't work - causes error 500

Tags: php

This is the code that won't work, when I try to view this page in my browser (chrome), I get a 500 internal error. Could someone help?

```
<?php
$user = $_POST["user"];
$pass = $_POST["pass"];
$name = someuser;
$passw = somepassword;
if (!isset($_POST['login_button'])) {

} else {
if (&user == $name) {
      if ($pass == $passw) {
          setcookie('liamblogprox', 'hi', );
          header.location('http://liamwli.co.uk/proxy/proxy.php');
      } else {
      echo "Invalid User or Pass!"; }

}else {
echo "Invalid User or Pass!"; }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css" media="screen,projection" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="generator" content="GiffHost - http://www.giffhost.co.uk/" />
    <title>Private Proxy</title>
<style type="text/css">
#container #content center table tr td center h1 i b {
    color: #000;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="container">

      <div id="header">
        <h1>Private Proxy</h1>
            This is a paid super fast Proxy</div>

        <div id="subheader">
          <ul id="navigation">
                <li><a href="index.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="register.html">Register</a></li>
                <li class="active"><a href="login.html">Log In</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>

      </div>

      <div id="content">

<center>
<table bgcolor="white" cellpadding="12" border="1">
<tr><td colspan="2" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><center>
  <h1><i><b>Log In</b></i></h1></center></td></tr>
<tr><td><h1><i><b>UserName:</b></i></h1></td><td><form name="login" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>" method="post"><input
name="user" type="text"></td></tr>
<tr><td><h1><i><b>Password:</b></i></h1></td><td><input name="pass"
type="password"></td></tr>
<tr><td><center><input type="submit" value="Login"
name="login_button"></center></td><td><center><br><input
type="Reset"></form></td></tr></table></center> 
      </div>
        <div id="footer">

      Designed by<a href="http://www.giffhost.co.uk"> GiffHost </a></div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `setcookie('liamblogprox', 'hi', );` looks like you are missing an argument

Comment: You usually get `500 internal _server_ error`-messages, when your _server_ has a problem. Have a log at the error.log

Comment: `header.location('http://liamwli.co.uk/proxy/proxy.php');` << This is not legal PHP.

Comment: Learn to indent your code. It's very messy. The first if statement is pointless, plus it's an inverse condition which isn't good practice. Furthermore, you have an error at setCookie. There shouldn't a comma before the end of the right hand bracket.

Comment: Besides all the other code mistakes already mentioned by others, your server should also be logging the errors somewhere which should help you pinpoint things a bit easier. This might be a file called `error_log` within the current directory, or in `/var/log/` if your on linux among other places. That should be the first place you look.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are quite a few things wrong here.

```
<?php
// Are these actual login credentials? They should be quoted anyway.
$name = "alex";
$passw = "liamgoogle4530";

// This is a better way of checking to see if the form has been posted
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') 
{
    // The post variables are only likely to exist if the form has been submitted
    $user = $_POST["user"];
    $pass = $_POST["pass"];

    // $ sign, not & for $user variable, why not combine the check into one?
    if ($user == $name && $pass == $passw) 
    {
        // You need to set an expiry on the cookie, I've set it to one hour
        setcookie('liamblogprox', 'hi', time()+3600);
        // This is how you do redirects in PHP
        header('Location: http://liamwli.co.uk/proxy/proxy.php');
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "Invalid User or Pass!"; 
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for this :) I guess it's late, and i'm also a noob :( This is the best way to learn, though, so thanks. How would I make the time be a session cookie? Thats what the tutorial I read said....

Comment: You don't have to set a expiry on the cookie.  You can leave it out, and it'll expire when the browser closes.

Comment: Thanks :) I did remove it and it worked. Everything now works fine :)

Answer (score 4):

For starters, this could be a problem:

```
$name = alex;
$passw = liamgoogle4530;
```

Should probably be something like:

```
$name  = "alex";
$passw = "liamgoogle4530";
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's your code rewritten:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') 
{
    if ($_POST['user'] == 'alex' && $_POST['pass'] == 'liamgoogle4530') 
    {
        setcookie('liamblogprox', 'hi');
        header('Location: http://liamwli.co.uk/proxy/proxy.php');
        die();
    } 
    else 
    {
      echo 'Invalid User or Pass!'; 
    }
}
```

NOTE: After you do `header("Location: wherever.com");` always put `die` afterwards.

And the problems in your code:

You have an error here:

```
setcookie('liamblogprox', 'hi', );
```

There should be no comma at the end before the right bracket.

You have an error here:

`header.location('http://liamwli.co.uk/proxy/proxy.php');`

That's not valid PHP.

```
$name = alex;
$passw = liamgoogle4530;
```

Invalid PHP again. You're not casting the variables to strings.

```
if (&user == $name) {
```

Invalid PHP again.

Really you should have picked up on this. If you don't have error reporting switched on, please enable it. And always check your servers error logs.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is attempting to set a string, but it is not encapsulated in single quotes

```
$name = alex;
$passw = liamgoogle4530;
```

Should read:

```
$name = 'alex';
$passw = 'liamgoogle4530';
```

You should read some PHP basics at http://www.php.net

Also note that reading your web server's error logs will give you more specific details in the event of a 500 error.

**Edit**

Upon further review, your code has many syntax errors. You should look into configuring your error reporting to help you overcome these quickly while developing.

Comment: Upon further review, your code has many syntax errors.  You should look into configuring your error reporting to help you overcome these quickly while developing.

Comment: That is a very broad question with no knowledge about your hosting company, their practices, and the organization of your VPS.  Does your hosting company offer support?  If so, they'd be the best to help you with this.

Comment: shouldn't this be developed locally and deployed remotely? (that solves the VPS issue)

Comment: It's an unmanaged VPS. I manage it all. I s'pose i should get some error software....

Comment: No software, just make sure display_errors is turned on and error_reporting is set to something sane in your php.ini

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because of

```
 header.location('http://liamwli.co.uk/proxy/proxy.php');
```

This page doesn't exists. Give up a valid location

**EDIT**

Your way to redirect is wrong, it should be:

```
 header('Location: http://liamwli.co.uk/proxy/proxy.php');
```

Comment: It might not be that the page doesn't exist but simply that `header.location` is not a valid PHP call.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the quotes:

```
$name = "alex";
$passw = "liamgoogle4530";
```

Also a typo here:

```
if ($user == $name) {
```

And the forwarding should be:

```
header("Location: http://...")
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an ampersand in front of user on line 9 instead of a dollar sign.

```
if (&user == $name) {
  if ($pass == $passw) {...
```